# Is it safe to run multiple powershell scripts concurrently?

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, concurrency, nic

I've adapted a powershell script from here https://www.pdq.com/blog/using-powershell-to-set-static-and-dhcp-ip-addresses-part-1/ to set an IP address on a NIC adapter in Windows. I have Python code that spawns a powershell process and points to the script that does the work. This may be a very obscure question but **I am wondering how safe it is to run multiple such scripts simultaneously assuming they all modify the same adapter?**

My code isn't what I'm worried about. I'm worried that there may be race conditions on the adapter or it may cause other unforeseen errors. What do you think? Also, would using ip addr add on unix systems pose similar risks?

Comment: What [actual problem](https://xyproblem.info/) are you trying to resolve with such approach?¨

Comment: ^ I've designed my function to be able to add multiple IPs to a NIC at once. The reason the code is designed this way is because I need to make a UAC request to be able to run commands. So if there's multiple IPs to add -- its undesirable to have to click a new UAC request each time. There is no reason why I can't run the commands sequentially once the UAC request is accepted -- but I wanted to know if anything adverse could happen if trying to run multiple commands at the same time (for performance reasons.)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to worry about having multiple scripts for the same job. The script you copied is already checking if your parameter is changed, if not it does nothing. Otherwise it will change it to your defined parameter.